# The best way to customize a action bar menu?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm new in android programming, I want to create the GUI of my app, when making that the action bar must be customized to looks like :

[image]

here i have "three" things:

1. the button shape in the non-clicking state.
2. the button shape in the clicking state.
3. the buttons separator shape.

while searching i found somethings like [Android-actionbar](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar) and [ActionBar-Sherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/index.html) and i'm also familiar with how to customize the action bar and how to add buttons imagess and change it upon clicking, NOW, i don't know if there's is possibility to achieve my work using any of these methods, OR IF NOT, what's the best way.

Comment: How would you accommodate that much buttons in action bar?? Unless you are talking about action bar tabs.

Comment: @Naddy may be it will be less than that number, but i want the concept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at both these links.
[PagerTabStrip](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTabStrip.html)
[ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/)